# Simple JSON-RPC call to Bitcoin wallet with Apache Http Client 4 gives "failed to respond"

Tags: java, apache-httpclient-4.x, bitcoin, json-rpc, apache-httpcomponents

I'm trying to do simple **JSON-RPC** call to 'getinfo' method with no parameters with Apache Http-components HttpClient, but all I got is:

`org.apache.http.NoHttpResponseException: 127.0.0.1:33002 failed to respond`

My JSON RPC request is:

`{ "method": "getinfo", "params": [], "id": 1}`

And the code is:

```
CredentialsProvider credsProvider = new BasicCredentialsProvider();
credsProvider.setCredentials(
    new AuthScope( "localhost" , 33002 ) ,
    new UsernamePasswordCredentials( "loginxxx" , "passxxx" ) );

CloseableHttpClient client = HttpClients.custom()
    .setDefaultCredentialsProvider( credsProvider )
    .build();

HttpPost request = new HttpPost( "http://127.0.0.1:33002/jsonrpc" );

request.setEntity( new StringEntity( "{\"method\":\"getinfo\",\"params\":[],\"id\":1}" ) );

HttpResponse response = client.execute( request );
```

Why server is not responsing? How can I improve my **JSON-RPC** request?

Full trace log from apache: http://pastebin.com/K2HTZ4nR

Edit: changing both hostnames to 127.0.0.1 or both to localhost doesn't helps. Also putting id in \"1\" doesn't helps. `EntityUtils.consume` also doesn't helps. Removing `/jsonrpc` from `URL` also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The calling code is ok.** This issue comes when you configure `port` setting instead of `rpcport` in Bitcoin .

So I was connecting to some other service in Bitcoin wallet (propably just a bitcoin network service p2p server).

Answer (score 0):

```
DEBUG org.apac6.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 >> "POST / HTTP/1.1[\r][\n]"
DEBUG org.apac6.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 >> "Content-Length: 41[\r][\n]"
DEBUG org.apac6.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 >> "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=ISO-8859-1[\r][\n]"
DEBUG org.apac6.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 >> "Host: localhost:33002[\r][\n]"
DEBUG org.apac6.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 >> "Connection: Keep-Alive[\r][\n]"
DEBUG org.apac6.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 >> "User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.3.3 (java 1.5)[\r][\n]"
DEBUG org.apac6.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 >> "Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate[\r][\n]"
DEBUG org.apac6.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 >> "[\r][\n]"
DEBUG org.apac6.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 >> "{"method":"getinfo","params":[],"id":"3"}"
DEBUG org.apac6.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 << "end of stream"
```

There is something in the HTTP request message that makes the server-side request handler choke and drop the connection without returning a status code.

It is not easy to tell what exactly that can be but `Content-Type: text/plain; charset=ISO-8859-1` looks suspect to me. Content mime type probably be `application/json`.

Comment: Changing content-type to json doesn'y help. Refering to Bitcoin documentation, `text/plain` is ok: https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/API_reference_%28JSON-RPC%29